# Neighborhood of diagonal

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Consider a uniform space $X$ (with induced topology).

What of the following can be a subset of the other? Which of the following is always a subset of the other?

1. Neighborhood of the diagonal in the topology corresponding to $X\times X$.
2. The set of entourages of our uniformity.

Comment: "...with induced topology"....Induced *from where or what*?

Comment: Induced by the uniform structure, presumably.

Comment: The entourages are always neighbourhoods of the diagonal in the induced topology. I'll leave finding the proof to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Daniel Fisher wrote in a comment, every entourage is a neighborhood of the diagonal.  The converse fails, for example, if $X$ is the real line with the uniform structure induced by the usual metric.  Specifically, $\{(x,y): y<x+e^{-x}\}$ is an open neighborhood of the diagonal, but not an entourage (because its upper boundary gets too close to the diagonal for large $x$).

If I remember correctly, though, a *compact* Hausdorff space always has a unique uniform structure, and the entourages of this structure are exactly the neighborhoods of the diagonal.

Comment: Yes, you remember correctly, this is [Theorem 8.3.13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1XIq.png) from Engelking’s “General Topology”.